# -DWORD * float saved to signed long long - out of range or wrong casting?

Tags: c++, casting, range

I have the code:

```
float f = -6;
DWORD d = 7;
signed long long ll = -d * f; //should be 42
std::cout << ll;
```

But when I compile it (Visual Studio 2012, **Windows 7 x64**), I see the output:

```
-25769803776
```

And the debugger says:

```
    ll  -25769803776    __int64
    d   7               unsigned long
    f   -6.00000000     float
```

I don't understand why the result (`ll`) is not 42: `float f` and `DWORD d` have right values in debugger, `signed long long` have much "better" range and can hold both signed and unsigned values.

**Where is my mistake?**

Also, how to save (which type to use) the result of multiply by two `DWORD` or `DWORD` and `float` (before each of them there can be a `-` sign), e.g.:

```
-f * -f
-f * d
-d * d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d` is a 32bit unsigned integer. Meaning that `-d` is a very large positive number according to the C standard. For same-size integer calculations, this works fine, because the signed and unsigned values have the same form and `-d` will indeed be the "correct" form for -6 as an integer.

You can, assuming only lower 31 bits are used, cast it to a signed value. If the top bit is set (use `assert((d & 0x80000000) == 0)` to check that), then you will need to cast it to a 64-bit value first.

Alternatively, you can add parenthesis to negate the final result, which is in float:

```
 signed long long ll = -(d * f);
```

Casting to float will also work, and since the calculation is done in `float` anyway, the resulting value will be equally precise/imprecise whether you cast `d` to float or not - the compiler will do that either way.

Here's the code produced by clang in LLVM-IR form:

```
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %f = alloca float, align 4
  %d = alloca i32, align 4
  %ll = alloca i64, align 8
  store float -6.000000e+00, float* %f, align 4
  store i32 7, i32* %d, align 4
  %0 = load i32* %d, align 4
  %sub = sub i32 0, %0
  %conv = uitofp i32 %sub to float
  %1 = load float* %f, align 4
  %mul = fmul float %conv, %1
  %conv1 = fptosi float %mul to i64
  store i64 %conv1, i64* %ll, align 8
  ret i32 0
}
```

Note the `uitofp i32 %sub to float` - this is making `d` into a `float` value.

(Side-comment: I personally would choose 14 & 3 for an example giving 42, but good choice of a result anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You've negated an unsigned number. Try to do `-float(d) * f` instead. You should be able to see the effect if you do `DWORD e = -d;` and examine `e` in the debugger.

Comment: That's the point! But about float(d) - won't I miss precision? I mean for really big values (near the upper range of DWORD)? I checked that for DWORD d = 4294967200; float f = float(d) I miss 100 (float is 4294967300) - I guess it's acceptable, but it's the maximum difference?

Comment: Then you need to use a signed type which gives enough precision, like the `signed long long` you use for the final result. `-signed long long(d) * f` for example.

Comment: Note that casting `d` to signed long long first won't actually help, as the value is still converted to `float` after cast - it just converts from a 64-bit integer to a float instead of 32-bit unsigned int, but it's still becomes a float. If you want more bits, use `double` (and cast `d` to `double`).

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't pay any attention to the type of variable on the left-hand side of an assignment when it's doing a computation on the right-hand side.

That is, in your example, it *only* looks at "unsigned long" <strike>multiplied by "float"</strike> negated with a minus sign, and since the rules say that's done as an unsigned <strike>multiplication</strike> bit-complement, it will be.  *Later* it will put the result into `ll`, but that's not related!  The computation is done before the assignment, so they're totally separate.

An example which bites every C hacker on the ass at some time or another is this one, using the same types you use in your question:

```
__int64 x = 1 << 60;
```

That looks like it should put a number in `x` that has a **1** bit in its **60**'th position, right?  (Mathematically, that number would be 2 to the 60th power.) But because a bare 1 is considered an `int`, which is typically 32 bits wide, `1 << 60` is computed to be **0**, because there aren't 60 positions in a 32-bit integer!

"But I'm going to store it in `__int64 x`," you say.  *C doesn't care.*

Comment: "unsigned long multiplied by float, and since the rules say that's done as an unsigned multiplication" - No